# Create Matlab figures in LaTeX using matlabfrag or alternatives

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, matlab-figure, eps

I want to include Matlab figures into latex preferably with vectorised formats but with LaTeX MATLAB fonts for all text. I have been using the MATLAB function `matlab2tikz` which worked perfect for simple figures, but now my figures have too many data points which cause an error. So `matlab2tikz` is not suitable.

I've been looking at `matlabfrag` which I think will accomplish what I want, but when I run the script in LaTeX as detailed by the user guide it has an error `File not found`.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\begin{document}
\psfragfig{FileName}
\end{document}
```

Where `FileName` is the name of the .eps and .tex that `matlabfrag` creates. Has anyone come across this problem? Or recommend any other functions/methods to use?

I'm using Texmaker on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to rethink your workflow.

**Instead of reusing your *Matlab code to plot figures*** and be dissappointed by ever changing outputs with `matlab2tikz`, **start reusing your *latex code to plot figures*** and don't bother about plotting in Matlab anymore (at least not for beautiful plots).

`matlab2tikz` is just generating latex code based on the latex-package `pgfplots`. To understand the working of this package is pretty easy, as it is intended to be similar to Matlab.

So why bother and always let `matlab2tikz` do the work for you? Because again and again you won't be entirely happy with the results. Just try to write the pgfplots-code from scratch and **just load the data** from Matlab.

Here is a convenient function I wrote to create latex-ready text files:

```
function output = saveData( filename, header, varargin )

in = varargin;

numCols = numel(in);

if all(cellfun(@isvector, in))
    maxLength = max(cellfun(@numel, in));
    output = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) [x(:); NaN(maxLength - numel(x) + 1,1)],in,'uni',0));
    fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
    fprintf(fid, [repmat('%s\t',1,numCols),'\r\n'], header{:});
    fclose(fid);
    dlmwrite(filename,output,'-append','delimiter','\t','precision','%.6f','newline', 'pc');
else
    disp('saveData: only vector inputs allowed')
end

end
```

Which could for example look like the following, in case of a bode diagram:

```
w   G0_mag  G0_phase    GF_mag  GF_phase    
10.000000   40.865743   -169.818991 0.077716    -0.092491
10.309866   40.345290   -169.511901 0.082456    -0.101188
10.629333   39.825421   -169.196073 0.087474    -0.110690
10.958700   39.306171   -168.871307 0.092787    -0.121071
11.298273   38.787575   -168.537404 0.098411    -0.132411
```

In your `tikzpicture` you can then just load that file by

```
\pgfplotstableread[skip first n=1]{mydata.txt}\mydata
```

and store the table into the variable `\mydata`.

Now check [**pfgplots**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) how to plot your data. You will find the basic plot command `\addplot`

```
\addplot table [x expr= \thisrowno{0}, y expr= \thisrowno{3} ] from \mydata;
```

where you directly access the columns of your text file by `\thisrowno{0}` (confusing, I know).

---

Regarding your problem with to many data points: pgfplots offers the key `each nth point={ ... }` to speed things up. But I'd rather filter/decimate the data already in Matlab.
The other way around is also possible, if you have to few data points the key `smooth` smoothes things up.