# Publication ready figures-Matlab

Tags: matlab, fonts, publish, figure

I want to create high-quality figures ready to be submitted for publication. What is the best font size, type of file to be saved as(.fig, .eps, .png?) and generally the characteristics required for a top-quality figure?

Comment: Imho, it is not possible to create really high quality figures with Matlab, without retouching them later with Illustrator etc. It may be possible to reach satisfying results for some people, but its a ton or work. So maybe [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870338/2605073) is a little inspiration for an alternative way.

Comment: I think it's possible. To export, use the package export_fig

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Of course it’s possible to create publication-ready plots with MATLAB, and it’s not a lot of work if you know what you’re doing. Surely not as much work as drawing in LaTeX!

Comment: What font to use depends on your personal preferences and those of the journal you’re submitting to. I think this question should be closed as opinion-based, but I’m closing it as dupe.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just don't agree, but I suppose it depends on everybody's standards. I gave up plotting with Matlab years ago, as feeding a reusable latex script with new data is way less work, than adapting and especially annotating Matlab plots. Annotating in Matlab is really pain in the ass. But as I said, its just my opinion.

Comment: @thewaywewalk: annotations are a pain in MATLAB, unless you ignore the default annotation tools and just manually draw arrows and text using axes coordinates. There are FEX submissions for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the paper editing software you use.

If you use Latex or Overleaf, exporting to PDF is the easiest/simplest/smallest-file-size one while keeping image quality as high as possible (i.e. vector format). My typical workflow is

1. create the plot, set font size to 18 o 20 use `set(gca,'fontsize',..)`.
2. `set(gcf,'paperpositionmode','auto');` this is important! it makes your figure what-you-see-is-what-you-get, so you can adjust figure sizes relative to the font size.
3. save as PDF or `print -dpdf` to export to the figure.
4. call `pdfcrop yourfigure.pdf` to remove the margins, pdfcrop is available on Linux/Mac, but also [available on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252330/install-and-use-pdfcrop-on-windows). If you can't install pdfcrop, you can also use inkscape to fit plot to page.
5. I usually try to make the figure in its final look using matlab commands (so it can be easily reproduced), but in case there are changes that I can;t make automatically, I will open the pdf using `inkscape` and manually edit.
6. if the figure is a 3D surface/mesh rendering with transparency, I will directly call `print -dpng -r300 myfile.png` to create a png bitmap image directly. Exporting to pdf generates huge file sizes and slow rendering.
7. once done, upload the pdf or png to overleaf, the platform accepts these formats directly.

If using older versions of MS Word, I had been exporting images to EPS and insert to keep the images in highest quality possible. However, since 2017, this feature was turned off

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/support-for-eps-images-has-been-turned-off-in-office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840

but one can still modify a registry key to turn it on.

Later MS Office accepts svg, which you can export from matlab.

Comment: Instead of `pdfcrop`, you can use [this File Exchange submission of mine](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35264-adjust-pdf-page) to set the PDF page size appropriately.

Comment: For MS Word, I use EMF.